# Background consisting of various pixels

Tags: pixel, paint.net

I tried to make a background like the following:

[image: Pixel background]

When zoomed in, you can see it consists of different shades of pixels. But I don't know how to make such kind of patterns. I think it's like a rectangle with different kinds of fills, like **15% light shade**, **15% darker shade**, etc.

How can I make something like this?

Comment: It's probably not supposed to be a pattern, but rather the opposite: noise. Were you thinking of drawing it one pixel at a time?

Comment: @Jongware. Haha, that was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing the name of such a texture is half the battle. This is technically "noise".

According to the [documentation](http://www.getpaint.net/doc/latest/EffectsNoiseMenu.html), Paint.NET comes with a standard Generate Noise menu option. To create this kind of texture, start with a blank beige background and then use Add Noise to make it look grainy.

The documentation does not say if there is a dialog or interactivity of any kind involved. If not (and then it lags behind software such as Photoshop), you may be able to enhance or suppress the actual average color by playing with changing the overall Brightness. You can also experiment with creating a noisy image at twice the required size and then downsize it.

I did not search [*] but I'm sure there is dedicated noisy image generator software to be found on the web.

[*] I'd write my own, probably based on the standard `random()` function available in many programming languages. If that's no good I'd look in on actual noise algorithms; Perlin noise, for example.[**]

[**] More likely actually, I'd probably use Photoshop.